# How to convert Unix time format to hh:mm coming from an API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, recharts

I'm quite new with React and using API's. I'm trying to make a graph with [Recharts](https://recharts.org/en-US) and I'm kinda stuck with something. The time data that I get from the API shows as Unix time format as shown here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZH3T.png
This is how I fetch the API data:

```
 const [devices, setDevices] = useState([] as IDeviceData[]);

 useEffect(() => {
        fetch("http://api...")
            .then(response => {
                if (response.ok) {
                    return response.json()
                } else if (response.status === 404) {
                    return Promise.reject('Error 404')
                } else {
                    return Promise.reject('There was an error: ' + response.status)
                }
            })
            .then(data => setDevices(data))
            .catch(error => navigate(
                `/sensors/${imei}/404-not-found/`,
                {
                    state: {
                        description: `No sensor found with: "${imei}"`
                    }
                },
            ));
    }, [imei, navigate, category]);
```

And this is how I show it in my graph:

```
                <ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height="100%">
                    <LineChart data={devices} margin={{ top: 5, right: 20, bottom: 5, left: 0 }}>
                        <Line type="monotone" dataKey={category} dot={{strokeWidth: '4'}} stroke="#0EA5E9" />
                        <CartesianGrid stroke="#ccc" strokeDasharray="5 5" />
                        <XAxis dataKey={"timestamp"}/>
                        <YAxis />
                        <Tooltip />
                    </LineChart>
                </ResponsiveContainer>
```

I have tried to make a timestamp converter function like this:

```
export function convertTimestampToDate(timestamp: string): string {
  return new Intl.DateTimeFormat('nl', {
    year: 'numeric',
    day: '2-digit',
    month: '2-digit',
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute: '2-digit',
    second: '2-digit',
  }).format(parseInt(timestamp));
}
```

I don't quite know how to use the API data that I've put inside `devices` within the `XAxis` component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to do that, here is how:

- in `XAxis` there is a prop [`tickFormatter`](https://recharts.org/en-US/api/XAxis#tickFormatter) which can help you
  format the `XAxis` label
- you should format the timestamp in the `Tooltip` too using
  [`labelFormatter`](https://recharts.org/en-US/api/Tooltip#labelFormatter)

then you have to pass `convertTimestampToDate` to those props

note that in `convertTimestampToDate` you have to convert the timestamp to a date using `new Date()` because [`Intl.DateTimeFormat().format()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/format#syntax) accepts a date as a parameter

```
export function convertTimestampToDate(timestamp: string): string {
  return new Intl.DateTimeFormat('nl', {
    year: 'numeric',
    day: '2-digit',
    month: '2-digit',
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute: '2-digit',
    second: '2-digit',
  }).format(new Date(timestamp));
}

<ResponsiveContainer width='100%' height='100%'>
    <LineChart data={devices} margin={{ top: 5, right: 20, bottom: 5, left: 0 }}>
        <Line
            type='monotone'
            dataKey={category}
            dot={{ strokeWidth: '4' }}
            stroke='#0EA5E9'
        />
        <CartesianGrid stroke='#ccc' strokeDasharray='5 5' />
        <XAxis dataKey='timestamp' tickFormatter={convertTimestampToDate} />
        <YAxis />
        <Tooltip labelFormatter={convertTimestampToDate} />
    </LineChart>
</ResponsiveContainer>
```

check the codesandbox example

[image: Edit simple-line-chart (forked)]

Comment: Although you solution is working, when I completely refresh my page (cmd+shift+r) it get an `Invalid time value` error.

Comment: it might because the chart is rendering before it receives the data, can you try to conditionally render it using `devices && ( chart components go here )`

Comment: Can you maybe elaborate a little more? I haven't used conditional rendering in React yet so I don't know where to put it exactly. @mocherfaoui

Comment: I've updated the codesandbox with an example of conditional rendering, if you had any other issues just reply

Comment: Thank you so much! I take a look into conditional rendering for sure.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would go with a Javascript date library like: [DayJS](https://day.js.org/) or [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/) or [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/). They make the life of working with dates so much easier.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! For the project that I'm working on, we want to use a few as possible libraries.